# How to switch to VS Code linux keymap on GoLand?

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins, jetbrains-ide, goland, keymapping

VS Code `Linux` keymap differs slightly from the `Windows` keymap. I am using **VS Code Keymap** by JetBrains on GoLand on Fedora but it defaults to Windows keymap. I am used to Linux keymap and many common keyboard shortcuts are not working (e.g Formatting). Is there any way to switch this behavior? I couldn't find any settings to do that.

Comment: You can take necessary keymap from source code: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/platform/platform-resources/src/keymaps then copy it to `configurationDir/keymaps`: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory

Comment: Thanks, that will work but I am looking for a less manual solution. I don't want to super-refine my experience.